# VPN Client with Public Static IP [Route interface traffic to SIngle IP]

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, openvpn

I have an internet connection which doesn't provide any public static IP. So was looking for solution to provide Public Static IP to Local Machine - which includes SSH from that IP to the Machine. True Public static IP.

I already have a server with OpenVPN setup, but I can't find any solution for routing an interface traffic to a single IP, including all ports etc.

Below is my idea.

```
Client connects via eth0 to VPN Server
|---------------------------------------|
eth0 ------\                            |
            SERVER(VPN Server) ---- VPN CLIENT (10.0.8.1)
eth1 ------/                           /||\ 
 /||\                                   ||
  ||====================================||
  All traffic of eth1 to VPN client(10.0.8.1)
```

I tried different ways to route traffic but they didn't work. If anyone can provide IP tables rules, that will be really helpful.

In short, I am looking to DIY https://vpnstaticip.com/

Comment: Can I move this question to super user ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1274988/vpn-client-with-public-static-ip-route-interface-traffic-to-single-ip  Reposted same question.

Answer (score 1):

Get a Domain from a provider such as dyndns which will always update your public dynamic ip to a domain name.

Route the traffic to the domain name?

Comment: I am not getting public IP of any sort. They have internal IP's.

Comment: Add it to the host file?